# Rails, Highcharts - dynamic render from column

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have an integer column in my table containing a number associated with each record and I am trying to render this number on to a single bar for each record.

```
<script>
var charts = [],
    $containers = $('#trellis1'),      


$.each(datasets, function(i, dataset) {
    charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: $containers[i],
            type: 'bar',
            marginLeft: i === 0 ? 100 : 10
        },

        title: {
            text: null,
            align: 'left',
            x: i === 0 ? 90 : 0
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Difficulty'],
            labels: {
                enabled: i === 0
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 5
        },


        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

         plotOptions: {
            series: {
                color: '#FF0000'
            }
        },

        series: [{
          <% @homeworks.each do |homework| %>
              data: <%= homework.feedback_request %>;
              <% end %>
            }],

    }));
});
</script>
```

Here is my table:

```
    <% @homeworks.where(feedback_request: 1).find_each do |homework| %>
                    <% if homework.school_user.user_id == current_user.id %>
                    <% if current_user.teacher? %>
                    ....
                    <td height="1"><div id="trellis1" class="inline">&emsp;&ensp;</div></td>
    ....
                    </td>
                  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The page loads but nothing renders in the div for the chart. I don't need to do any calculations or anything. It's just an integer column with a single number for each record. If I hard code in data it shows. Is my syntax ok?

Any guidance? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Page source - can see data is being returned

```
...
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

         plotOptions: {
            series: {
                color: '#FF0000'
            }
        },

        series: [{
              data: 1;
              data: 1;
              data: 1;
              data: 1;
            }],

    }));
});
```

Controller - this is where the problem might be I think. The Kaminari pagination gem is messing up the view because i'm using ransack. It says its paginating by 4 (hence in the source 4 returned) yet in my view I visually only see two records which is the correct and what I want.

```
def revision_bucket
        @homework = Homework.where(:school_user_id => current_user.id)
        @q = Homework.search(params[:q])
        **@homeworks = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per(4)**
        @q.build_condition if @q.conditions.empty?
        @q.build_sort if @q.sorts.empty?
    end
```

I think I need to fix this but i'm not sure how. Can provide more info as needed. Thanks.

UPDATE

How I fixed this:

In controller...

```
@interest = Homework.last.homework_students.pluck(:interest).reduce(:+) / Homework.last.homework_students.pluck(:interest).size
```

Table same as above...

And in Highcharts JS:

```
 <script>
    var charts = [],
        $containers = $('#trellis2'),
         datasets = [{
            data: [<%= @interest %>]}];

    $.each(datasets, function(i, dataset) {
        charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: $containers[i],
                type: 'bar',
                marginLeft: i === 0 ? 100 : 10
            },

    ....

            series: [dataset]




}));
});
```

Comment: Are You sure that nothing renders to the div? Sometimes in highcharts, you have to set height of a container div.

Comment: Hi, I have set the height and width, I tried increasing and no change. It works if I hard code in data though...

Comment: I would suggest to try to create variable, instead of passing data straight to series array.

Than You can console.log(data) in JS.

Comment: Can you show the source page which includes only html/js?

Comment: @grzesiekgs hi, thanks, updated OP with additional info. I suspect pagination may be to blame. But i would like the best way to do this too. What would be the best approach? I'm still quite new to rails.

Comment: @morganfree posted source but pagination is at odds with the view. Think it needs to be cleaned but not sure how.

Comment: The series array has an incorrect format. Each object should have one property data. Data should be an array of points (array of single values, array of arrays of values or objects) http://jsfiddle.net/u5kc506u/

Comment: @morganfree thanks I got it working but it only renders once. I want to render multiple charts with different values in the one table using the div in OP. But I have no idea how to achieve this? Thanks for help.

Comment: I cannot help you with rails but make sure you have the correct config object for a chart. http://jsfiddle.net/u5kc506u/1/